# Convert an image from progressive to interlaced without losing quality or details?

Tags: php, image, converters, progressive

I'm trying to retrieve large images from a directory outside of the root directory. At the moment I just use "fpassthru", but this loads the image either progressively or interlaced depending on what is was when uploaded.

How do I create a complete copy of an image but convert it to interlaced without losing any quality or detail with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the GD libraries that come with PHP, you can use [`imageinterlace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageinterlace.php) to accomplish this.

Here's from the example:

```
<?php
// Create an image instance
$im = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');

// Enable interlancing
imageinterlace($im, true);

// Save the interlaced image
imagegif($im, './php_interlaced.gif');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Alternately, you could use [ImageMagick](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/events/courses/1996/cmwh/Stills/manipulating.html#Interlacing).

Comment: Does that preserve everything the image had? E.g. If it was a png and was interlaced, would that transfer over when I use createimagefrompng?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say, if the PNG was transparent, would it preserve that.

Comment: That's where the transparency and alpha functions come in.  Have you tried processing a transparent PNG with the interlace function yet?